# wordpress slider product like google play?

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for silder product plugin or code for wordpress site.
the slider looks like one of https://play.google.com/store
Please help me.
thank you so much!

Comment: Please help! I really need it. I were searching around, but it's seem nothing for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

i've found some code that should help you : http://oldmill1.github.io/posts/google-play-slider.html